# mongodb facet with root

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, facet

Is there a way to push root documents to specific field on `$facet` without `$group` ? For example,

```
db.artwork.aggregate( [
  {
    $facet: {
      "categorizedByTags": [
        { $unwind: "$tags" },
        { $sortByCount: "$tags" }
      ],
      "items": [{$push: "$$ROOT"}] // I want to push all root document to `items`.
    }
  }])
```

Comment: just use `"items": []`, itself collect root documents.

Comment: @turivishal When I user empty array, mongodb raise error. "$facet stage cannot be empty."

Comment: see the working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ca1e0SVAcnQ) might be it is version issues you can try answer by @Tom

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use an empty `$match`, like so:

```
db.artwork.aggregate( [
  {
    $facet: {
      "categorizedByTags": [
        { $unwind: "$tags" },
        { $sortByCount: "$tags" }
      ],
      "items": [{$match: {}}]
    }
  }])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
db.artwork.aggregate( [
{
 $facet: {
   items: [ { $match: {} } ],
  }
 }
])
```